# Adapting parse server to use auth0?

Tags: parse-server, auth0

Has anyone tried to adapt [parse server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) to use the auth0 [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) authentication mechanism?

I.e. I'd like my mobile app users to authenticate via auth0, then make requests to my self-hosted parse server with the http header including the `Bearer jwt` token provided by auth0. My parse server with express-jwt would validate the token, extract the `user_id` and then I can use that in the parse server per usual as a key for that user.

Am I thinking about this the right way? Anyone tried this already? Perhaps it's trivial to integrate auth0 into express and thus parse server will "just work"?

Comment: I think that you will need to create your own custom authentication in order to achieve that kind of functionality. you can read more about it here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/OAuth 
if you decide to do it then you can contribute it to parse-server